# removeFromSuperview and addSubview relation with reference count?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm working on an application in which i'm doing lot of addSubview and removeFromSuperview, but application is crashing due weak memory management. I want to know whether addSubview increments the reference count of the view added by one? and does removeFromSuperView decrements the reference count by one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to release subviews](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976345/how-to-release-subviews)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they do. In general, whenever you add an object to a collection (which includes an object's array of subviews), it will increment its retain count.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you create a view like this:

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

The retain count is 1 and you are the owner.

If you add this view to another view, the second view will be the owner of it, and will increase the count, so you need to release:

```
[mySecondView addSubView:myView];
[myView release];
```

Now, if you want to remove that view, you do:

```
[myView removeFromSuperView];
```

And your view will be completely released cause removeFromSuperView decrement the count.

So, summarizing:

- alloc and addSubView will increase your count by 1 each
- release and removeFromSuperview will decrement your count by 1 each

Answer (score 0):

yes exactly ... addSubView will increment the reference count of the view by one and removeFromSuperView will decrement it also by one .. if you are facing some problems in memory management try to trace the reference count of your views maybe its not being released.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right **addSubView** increase the reference count of view being added and **removeFromSuperView** decreases by one.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `addSubview` does increase the reference count, therefore you need to release the view you are adding after calling `addSubview`

See the [Apple UIView reference document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) where for addSubview it states "This view is retained by the receiver".